# Love2D - how to math.floor the love.graphics.scale result?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm using the Gamera library for my game's camera and so as to be compatible with multiple screen resolutions on mobile I'm using the setScale function with Gamera to adjust the size accordingly. Gamera uses love.graphics.scale to scale the graphics and unfortunately this results in a sub pixel figure for the graphic size since the scale ratio is a decimal number. The screen visible area is resized to perfect integers however so there is no problem there.

This sub pixel figure for the graphic size causes pixel bleed when drawing tiles with Sprite batches. I've tried "nearest neighbour" image filtering for these problem images, which was a workaround but didn't fix the pixel bleed for the player's y axis. Generally I thought there must be a better way since all that really needs to be done is to math.floor the scale. The 2048x2048 level size is resized to something like 1742.8234. If it was simply 1742 there would be no problem.

This is the relevant draw function in Gamera:

```
function gamera:draw(f)
  love.graphics.setScissor(self:getWindow())

  love.graphics.push()
    local scale = self.scale
    love.graphics.scale(scale)

   love.graphics.translate((self.w2 + self.l) / scale, (self.h2+self.t) / scale)
   love.graphics.rotate(-self.angle)
   love.graphics.translate(-self.x, -self.y)

   f(self:getVisible())

  love.graphics.pop()

  love.graphics.setScissor()
end
```

Comment: and what stops you from using math.floor(scale) then? what is your problem?

Comment: @Piglet Well how do you do it then? I've no idea how you would do it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use math.floor on your scale, all you have to do is to replace any occurance of scale where you want to do that with math.floor(scale).

```
function gamera:draw(f)
  love.graphics.setScissor(self:getWindow())

  love.graphics.push()
    local scale = self.scale
    love.graphics.scale(math.floor(scale))

   love.graphics.translate((self.w2 + self.l) / math.floor(scale), (self.h2+self.t) / math.floor(scale))
   love.graphics.rotate(-self.angle)
   love.graphics.translate(-self.x, -self.y)

   f(self:getVisible())

  love.graphics.pop()

  love.graphics.setScissor()
end
```

As programmers are lazy and we do not want to calculate things more often than necessary this solution is not very pretty. So we forget what we did above and simply replace

```
local scale = self.scale
```

with

```
local scale = math.floor(self.scale)
```

now within that function `scale` is uses as intended.

If we want keep that change beyond that function's scope we could as well do

```
self.scale = math.floor(self.scale)
local scale = self.scale
```

**Edit** due to comment

If you want to use ensure that love.graphics.scale() results in integer dimensions you have to use an appropriate scale.

Sticking to your example:

2048 shall be shrinked to 1742:

```
love.graphics.scale(1742/2048)
```

If you let's say want to shrink it to 30%:

```
love.graphics.scale(math.floor(0.3*2048)/2048)
```

would result in 614 instead of 614.4

Simple math.

Comment: My question was "how to math.floor the love.graphics.scale **result**?" That is just a math.floor of the scale value...

Comment: @Hasen you said: "Generally I thought there must be a better way since all that really needs to be done is to math.floor the scale". And in your example scale is an input argument to love.graphics.scale(). If you don't like how this funciton works feel free to build your own Love2d. It's open source. so change whatever you need. but the correct way would be to change scale so the result would be an integer because the function itself does exactly what it is supposed to.

Comment: the scale figure 1742/2048 is the scale in my example..if you math floor that you're still just doing a math.floor on the scale and not the result. You're just turning 0.85 into 1 or 0 which is no use at all. The result of scaling it with love.graphics.scale or 0.85 would be 1742.23245234 or whatever but it needs to be an integer ie 1742.

Comment: to put it simply, love.graphics.scale is a function, it requires a scale value like 0.32, 0.85 or 1.47. That number we do not want to math.floor because it is a decimal. Then love.graphics.scale generates a number to scale the graphics which will be something like 1780.3234, 2321.428 etc. It's THIS number that needs to be floored.

Comment: @Hasen math.floor(0.3*2048)/2048 is 0.2998046875 how is this an integer scale? math.floor(0.85) is 0, not 1 or 0 btw.  you said your goals was to get integer level size which can be achieved as explained. If you cannot follow me I'm sorry. Maybe you should read my answer again and watch those parentheses carefully. "to put it simply" you know the input size so you can calculate a scale factor that will give you an integer output.

Comment: I don't see the point in doing math.floor in the scale sent to love.graphics.scale. This does not affect how the graphics are scaled in `love:draw`. ie it does not affect the `love.graphics.scale` **result**. I just tested it and it indeed does not. In fact your code is the same as simply `love.graphics.scale(1742/2048)`

Comment: @Hasen if you scale a 2048 level with 1742/2048 you'll get a level size of 1742. that's what you requested. you wanted an integer level size. what's wrong with it? I don't get your problem. what is it you cannot understand here?

Comment: That's the level/map size that will be resized with `love.graphics.scale` but the scale ratio will be based on the *screen* size. So for example the scale ratio is based on iPhone 6 resolution which is 1334/750 so on an iPhone 5 it will be 1136x640 which will need to scale down. So for argument's sake let's say the scale will be 1136/1334 which is 0.85157 etc which will then scale the graphics on an iPhone 5 device. ie the level size which is 2048 will be scaled by 0.85157...and the result will *not* be an integer.

Comment: @Hasen of course 0.85157 results in a non-integer size. 0.85157*2048=1744.01536. that's why you have calculate a scale factor that will give you the respective floored number.... math.floor(0.85157*2048)/2048 = 0.8515625; 
0.8515625*2048 = 1744. you wanted your size to be scaled to an integer, here you go. So either you are unable to explain what you want or you don't understand my solution.

Comment: it seems it always causes an issue because games are made up of tiles and 2048 pixels contains 32 x 64 pixel tiles...but 1744 contains 32 x 54.4 tiles with that scale ratio. You'd have to get it to equal 1728 which is 32 x 54 but it wouldn't fit the screen properly...might not be noticeable though.

Comment: actually just forget about it, it seems to be a fundamental problem with love.graphics.scale in Love2d. Even with 0.5 scaling which would make the level 1280 and the tiles 32 pixels it still has artifacts like pixel bleed and flickering going on which obviously shouldn't be happening. It should only be having this kind of problem with subpixels but that's clearly not the case here. They can be solved with an imgfilter but that sometimes causes other problems and shouldn't be required anyway.

Thanks for your efforts anyway.